# How does one obtain the file path of the current .blend in the bge?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, path

Specifically, how does one obtain the path to the current .blend when the blender game engine is running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine this with [`bge.logic.expandPath("//")`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.expandPath). It will give you the directory that the current blend-file is in excluding the filename.